# How to stop Visual Studio from locating .NET *.cs files during debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug third party code using dotPeek as a symbol server. The debugger stops at  breakpoints in that code. However, the debugger is also trying to locate .cs files that belong to the .NET framework as shown below and I have to cancel in all kinds of these files.
I am also using Microsoft symbol servers and not excluding anything belonging to the framework therefore I expect VS to not ask for these files.
Using VS 17.7.1. 'Just my code' is unchecked.

I tried all kinds of settings and VS keeps trying to locate these files.
Is there a way to ignore .NET Framework code during debugging?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you turn off 'Just My Code', want to debug 3rd party code/packages, and use "Step into(F11)", then this situation is unavoidable.

I can reproduce your situation:

[image]

If you are debugging 3rd party code and encountered this issue in it, the only way is to decompile the source code or give the cs file it needs. After that, close VS and turn on it again.

In your situation, you need to make sure this place has the source code unless you can use F10 to debug:

[Access decompiled files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Accessing_Decompiled_Files.html)

or You can set the Microsoft Symbol server and decompile the source code(cs file is just a place to perform/show, where it comes from is not important.).

After the above steps, the xxx.cs not found will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. VS is decompiling these assemblies using ILSpy. Why isn't able to know where the .cs files are and asking the user to provide the path? The .cs files are the output of the decompilation therefore it should know where they are. In some temporary folder. Rider doesn't have this issue. It just steps into decompiled code without asking the user for .cs locations